# How do i invalidate a session if i copy paste the URL in a TAB or a different browser after loging, I am using JSF2.0

Tags: redirect, jsf-2, servlet-filters

Here is the code i am trying to apply, current i am trying Filter but does not redirect to login.jsf.

```
package com.session.testing;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.cosmos.util.FacesUtils;

/**
* Servlet Filter implementation class SessionServ
*/


public class SessionServ implements Filter {

FilterConfig fc;

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public SessionServ() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see Filter#destroy()
 */
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
 */


public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,  FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {


    System.out.println("Entered intop Login Filter");





    HttpServletRequest request1 = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse response1 = (HttpServletResponse) response;
  // HttpSession session = request1.getSession(false);
    HttpSession session = request1.getSession(true);
    String pageRequested = request1.getRequestURL().toString();
    //testing 1

   System.out.println(" get the URL getRequestURL+ "+pageRequested);
    if (session.getAttribute("userName") != null &&  !pageRequested.contains("login.jsf")) {
        //chain.doFilter(request, response);
        session = request1.getSession(false);
        session.invalidate();
        response1.sendRedirect("login.jsf"); // No logged-in user found, so   redirect to login page.
    } 

    else {
        System.out.println("starting from chain.dofilter");
        //response1.sendRedirect("login.jsf");
        chain.doFilter(request, response); // Logged-in user found, so just continue request.
    }







 }





/**
 * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
 */
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    fc=fConfig;
}

}
```

Filter does not work for redirecting the page to login page but initializes during the logging. 
Web.xml

```
<filter>
<display-name>SessionServ</display-name>
<filter-name>SessionControl</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.session.testing.SessionServ</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>SessionControl</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/EMISession/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Where have i gone wrong, I tried the example from Balus

Comment: You are right, i tried with 'logout', 'sessionID'. Had the same issue as well do difference.

Comment: Still haven't got the answer seems to be a tough solutions for JSF